# Failed to connect to localhost port 5000: Connection refused with Docker

Tags: docker, curl

I have build my small Python(flask ) app.Container is here
docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
4146fd976547        identidock_identidock:latest   "/cmd.sh"           5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        9090/tcp, 9191/tcp   agitated_leakey
```

If I try

```
curl localhost:5000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5000: Connection refused
```

I have checked
sudo netstat -an | grep -E "5000"
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     25000

It is not listeting on 5000.
yaml line with ports

```
  ports:
   - "5000:5000"
```

If I exec my container

```
docker exec -it agitated_leakey /bin/bash
uwsgi@4146fd976547:/app$ netstat -ln
bash: netstat: command not found
```

My Dockerfile

```
RUN pip install Flask==0.10.1 uWSGI==2.0.8
WORKDIR /app
COPY app /app
COPY cmd.sh /

EXPOSE 9090 9191
```

Why this happens?

Comment: can you ssh to docker container and netstat to check if the port is listening. Was docker port 5000 exposed ?

Comment: @Dextro67 Take a look at my edit,please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative issue can be with the mode. In the publish section I had to set the `mode` explicitly to host and everything worked:

`docker service create --name registry --publish published=5000,target=5000,mode=host registry:2`

Answer (score 2):

From the docker ps output seems that your port has not been exposed.

```
$ docker run -d -p 5000:5000 flask-sample-one
```

Run your container mapping the port and if you still face same issue ssh to the container and use the following command.

```
netstat -lntp | grep :5000
```

Seems netstat is not installed in the container. You can run a `yum install netstat` to install and check.

[This](http://containertutorials.com/docker-compose/flask-simple-app.html) guide will help you to verify. Check `docker ps` output at the end.